# Position in Html

Tags: html

I created a div tag at the beginning of my document in html with specified width and height.  Now after closing the div tag, whenever I create other tags like the p tag they are always inside the div tag I created instead of at the bottom of the page.

Do I have to position every element? 
How many times do I have to use the relative and absolute positioning in a document?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please provide code samples so we can spot the problem

Answer (score 0):

An absolute positioned element is out of the normal flow of document so it not takes room. You should set dimensions for its relative parent manually to simulate a normal flow. You may use a fixed height in pixels or use aspect ratio Technics for percent dimensions.

A sample of relative `div` with no size:

```css
#test{
   position:relative;
}

#abs{
   position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="abs">
  This div will expand the relative parent with 0 pixels in height
  </div>
</div>

This text has overlap with previous element.
```

A sample of relative `div` with fixed size:

```css
#test{
   position:relative;
   height:60px;
   background:#ff0000;
}

#abs{
   position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="abs">
  This div is absolute but the parent has its own size
  </div>
</div>

This text has no overlap with previous element.
```

A sample of relative div with aspect ratio:

```css
#test{
   position:relative;
   padding-top:30%;
   background:#ff0000;
}

#abs{
   position:absolute;
   top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="abs">
  This div is absolute but the parent has its own aspect ratio 1:0.3
  </div>
</div>

This text comes after the previous element.
```

Finally I have to say that if you are a graphic designer and want to design a web page, you are not ought to design entire the page using relative and absolute elements. You have too many options to design a template using blocks, inline-blocks, tables , flex boxes etc. which regard the normal flow of document.

Comment: So you're saying that I need to position every thing on the document page?

Comment: I have added a paragraph at the end of answer about options in designing an HTML page. I hope it helps.@AnthonyIris